# How to add Visible Edit Shortcuts on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

My WordPress theme is not showing visible edit shortcuts in customizer, in menus, or any other place, but my sidebar template is showing the visible edit shortcuts. In my custom sections it shows when I don't select a page like in the TwentySeventeen Theme.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the issue you're having. But a few things that might help you figure out how to solve the issue:

1. Switch themes and see if the issue persists
   2  If the issue continues, deactivate all your plugins and turn them back on one by one to see if there's a conflict.

Finally, if you are trying to add edit buttons, you need to create a couple elements...

```
<input type="button" onclick"createEdit()" value="Edit">
```

and a javascript function...

```
<script>
function createEdit() {
   THE CONTENTS OF WHAT NEEDS TO BE ALTERED
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: **@PhysicsIsRelativelyCool** According to what ive found on my research they say i will use selective refresh extension like this one `$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'panel_' . $i, array( 'selector' => '#panel' . $i, 'render_callback' =>'ovstheme_front_page_section', 'container_inclusive' => true, ) );` I wanted to make this Appear on my website such as in Navigation menu, Header, Footer or Anywhere i would like to add them.

Comment: OP's question is extremely low quality and cannot be properly answered; which is why you don't fully understand their issue.  Your answer would be better served as a comment, since it does not address a specific issue.